# how can i overwrite an image saved in the photoalbum?(iPhone)

Tags: xcode, image, save, overwrite, picker

in my application, I take images from the photoalbum through pickerController, with this code:

```
 - (IBAction)getImageFromPhotoAlbum:(id) sender {
    pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    [self presentModalViewController:pickerController animated:YES];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    myImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}
```

to save an image I use this code:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

how I can save an image over a already existing image in the photoalbum?

thank

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

I doubt they would ever permit this either. If you think about it, the user is quite likely to want the original version so it is much better all round for any changes you make to be stored in a new photo. The user can then choose how to manage their collection as required.

Comment: now that us task, nobody would want that a app could modify a personal image.( excuse for my language, I am an Italian) :D